# Passing Value From TableViewCell To Another VC: Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I had a question. I wanted to pass a value from a tableviewcell and display it as a string on another view controller. I have used print(valueToPass!) and it does successfully print in the debugger however the label displays 'nil' in the actual label. I think it has something to do with the ! and ? but not too sure. If someone could have a look and help me out I would appreciate it a lot! Thanks.

TableView Code:

```
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "uploadItem", sender: self)
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "uploadItem" {
                    if let destination = segue.destination as? UploadItemViewController {
            
                        if self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil{
                            let rowIndex: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! as NSIndexPath
                
                            let selectedRow = tableView.cellForRow (at: rowIndex as IndexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell
                
                            valueToPass = selectedRow.itemName?.text!
                            print(valueToPass!)
                                    
                            destination.itemTitle?.text = valueToPass!
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

ViewController that I want to pass data in to

```
var selectedItem: AddItemTableViewController?
itemTitle.text! = "\(selectedItem?.valueToPass)"
```

Comment: That's because you don't send the value to a variable at the destination at first.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
destination.itemTitle?.text = valueToPass!
```

indeed 'valueToPass' carries a value and you assign it to "itemTitle" (which is property in the destination VC, I reckon?).

However, when the destination ViewController is loaded or appears, this line is executed next:

```
itemTitle.text! = "\(selectedItem?.valueToPass)"
```

and at that point, 'selectedItem' is nil, therefore nil is returned is that assignment, which runs over the previous assignment in the prepareForSegue. You need to init 'selectedItem' in the destination as well, before the init of 'valueToPass', and on viewDidAppear on destination, call the

```
itemTitle.text! = "\(selectedItem?.valueToPass)"
```

In the stage, since you know 'selectedItem' is initiated, you may even command the imperative way : selectedITme!.valueToPass